# Convert jQuery object into PHP array using HTML form

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

I have a jQuery object which is appended to form field like,

```
var params = {
    'product_id': productId,
    'width': width,
    'drop': drop
};

$("#sample-form input[name='params']").val(params);
```

Form looks like,

```
<form id="sample-form" action="url" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="params"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

On receiving this "params" using POST data in PHP, I get string with value "[object Object]"

How do I convert this into array?

Comment: You could use JSON. `...val(JSON.stringify(params))`. Then deserialise that value when sent to your PHP

Comment: Store it as stringified json `val(JSON.stringify(params));`. Then in PHP, you do: `$params = json_decode($_POST['params'], true);` to get it as a PHP array.

Answer (score 1):

I converted jQuery object into stringified JSON as,

```
$("#sample-form input[name='params']").val(JSON.stringify(params));
```

In PHP, convert received JSON into PHP array as,

```
$params = json_decode($_POST['params'], true);
```